# How to properly do a dynamic route in reactJs when working with Add to Cart ecommerce functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm making a e-commerce. For the add to cart, i defined an addToCartHandler as follows:

```
let params = useParams();
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productId = params.id;
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
  }, [dispatch, productId]);

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    navigate(`/cart/${productId}?qty=${qty}`);
  };
```

The URL renders correctly dan dynamically according to the productId and qty of the added to cart product

***Screenshot of the URL whenever the add to cart button is clicked***

[image]

But the **cartscreen** is empty even though the URL renders as expected. Here is the **CartScreen** code. Did it suppose to locate the quantity at the end of the URL after the? sign. Example URL: "/cart/2?qty=15". So I use `useLocation()` and search.split("=")[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCDDa.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function CartScreen(props) {
  let params = useParams();
  let location = useLocation();
  const productId = params.id;
  const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split("=")[1]) : 1;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Cart Screen</h1>
      <p>
        ADD TO CART : ProductID: {productId} Qty: {qty}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It returns an empty cart screen with the following error in the console:

```
No routes matched location "/cart/2?qty=15"
```

I guess it's because the route in App.js. But I'm not sure. My routes are as follows:

```
 <Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen />}></Route>
```

I'm actually following this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRCDsB9i3bI&t=9077s and the error I got is when I do the section 02:57:24 Part 14- Handle Add To Cart Button.

It might also have to do with the different react-router versions?

Here are my versions:

```
  "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "with-router": "^1.0.1"
```

And the versions of the tutorial are:

```
"axios": "^0.20.0",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
"react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.10",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"socket.io-client": "^4.0.1"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
<Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen />}></Route>
```

Use this:

```
<Route path="/cart/:id" element={<CartScreen />}></Route>
```

Just remove ? from path,
if it doesn't work use this code for CartScreen:

```
   const CartScreen = () => {
   const { id } = useParams();
   const productId = id;
   console.log("ID :", productId);
   const { search } = useLocation();
   const qtyInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get("qty");
   console.log("QTY", qtyInUrl);
   const qty = qtyInUrl ? Number(qtyInUrl) : 1;
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   useEffect(() => {
   if (productId) {
    dispatch(addToCart(productId));
    }
   }, [dispatch, productId]);

  return (
   <div>
    <h1>Cart Screen</h1>
    <p>
       Add to Cart : Product ID : {productId} QTY: {qty}
    </p>
  </div>
 );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

<Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen />}>

try to change to that and see if it works in your case:

<Route path="/cart/:id/*" element={<CartScreen />}>

Comment: Please, add some comments about your code and how does it answers the question.

Comment: just changed from 'optional' to 'wildcard', it might solve that particular problem.  I am also waiting for someone to give a better solution, which can just replace the '?' (optional) in the new version of react-router, instead of changing other parts of the codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export const CartScreen = () => {
    const qty = window.location.search?window.location.search.split("=")[1]:1
    const {id} =  useParams()
    const productId = id
  return (
  <div>
      <h1>Cart Screen</h1>
      <p>
          ADD TO CART : ProductID: {productId} Qty: {qty}
      </p>
  </div>
  );
};
```

Route code should look like this:

```
<Route path="/cart/:id/*" element={<CartScreen />}>
```